# Also show null results in phpMyAdmin query (PHP)

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I wrote this query to display the "estado" rows if they don't have the values "entregado" or "cancelado" everything works fine
The problem is that if a status row "estado" has the NULL value, it is not displayed, why?

How would I make it show up?

***Since my goal is only*** to hide the rows that have the values "entregado" or "cancelado"

This is my query in phpMyAdmin

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_AAAedubot` WHERE `celular` AND celular NOT LIKE 'Robot-%' AND estado NOT LIKE 'entregado' AND estado NOT LIKE 'cancelado' ORDER BY `wp_AAAedubot`.`time` DESC
```

Comment: If you aren't worried about case sensitivity, you can shorten this with `NOT IN ('entregado', 'cancelado')`

Comment: Yes, case insensitivity is important

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I fixed it this way I wonder if it will be ok**
It does its job but I don't know if I put it together correctly for better performance.

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_AAAedubot` WHERE `celular` AND
celular NOT LIKE 'Robot-%'AND
estado NOT LIKE 'entregado' AND
estado NOT LIKE 'cancelado' OR
estado IS NULL ORDER BY `wp_AAAedubot`.`time` DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing in your SQL which would prevent a row from being retrieved if `estado` is null. However, you are checking the `celular` column too, which is probably causing your issue.

To only hide the rows that have the values "entregado" or "cancelado", do this:

```sql
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  `wp_AAAedubot` 
WHERE 
  estado NOT LIKE 'entregado' AND 
  estado NOT LIKE 'cancelado';
```

Comment: Not working null value not showing :(